# Вывод постов на главной и в категориях wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Устанавливаю свою верстку на wordpress - и вот появился такой вопрос, как вывести посты на главную и в категории? 
Пробовал вот так:

```html
<?php if((is_category()) and (is_front_page())) { ?> 
 <div class="sekret">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 
<h2 class="sekret-number"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<h2 class="data"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></a></h2>
<h2 class="sekret-tag"><?php the_category(', '); ?></h2>
 <div class="content">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
  <div class="foot"></div>
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 <?php endif; ?>

     </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Но Посты вообще не выводятся. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не правильно?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php if((is_category()) || (is_front_page())) { ?> 
 <div class="sekret">
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 
<h2 class="sekret-number"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<h2 class="data"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></a></h2>
<h2 class="sekret-tag"><?php the_category(', '); ?></h2>
 <div class="content">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
  <div class="foot"></div>
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 <?php endif; ?>

     </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Разобрался